# `stack build` Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1

Tags: haskell-stack

I have a haskell stack project that built last week but I must have broken it while working on another haskell project elsewhere on my computer. I bumped my `stack` version, and now this build is failing without much detail. With higher `verbosity` values, my build prints a lot of warnings, but this is all the detail it prints about this build error:

```
$ stack build --verbosity error

--  While building package happy-1.19.5 using:
      /private/var/folders/kw/c01ws73s1xn996t2c_jt_fr00000gn/T/stack1958/happy-1.19.5/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build --ghc-options ""
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1


--  While building package alex-3.2.1 using:
      /private/var/folders/kw/c01ws73s1xn996t2c_jt_fr00000gn/T/stack1958/alex-3.2.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build --ghc-options ""
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Progress 12/61
```

my `stack.yaml`:

```
resolver: lts-8.12
packages:
- '.'
extra-deps: []
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
```

I tried `stack purge` and tried running with a much newer `resolver`, but neither of these helped.

I tried building `happy` on its own:

```
$ stack build happy-1.19.5
## (eliding lots of warnings) ##
happy> 9 warnings generated.
happy> clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
happy> Configuring happy-1.19.5...
happy> build
happy> Building happy-1.19.5...
happy> Preprocessing executable 'happy' for happy-1.19.5...
happy> setup: The program 'happy' is required but it could not be found
```

Any tips for getting this build to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a new project with `stack new my-project simple`, and installed them from there with

```
cd my-project
stack install alex
stack install happy
```

I don't understand how these dependencies are managed: it looks like they're just global tools that, though they are built with Haskell and hosted on Stackage, could be pulled in from anywhere. The versions I installed are different than the versions I used back when I originally authored my project, but it looks like things are working now ‍♂️.